# How can I use both these table elements in one HTML file in angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have these 2 `table` elements in my HTML file in one component, but it seems I can use only one of them. Is there a possibility for me to use both?

```
<table>
        
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>VOORNAAM</th>
            <th>ACHTERNAAM</th>
            <th>EMAIL</th>
            <th>WACHTWOORD</th>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor = "let item of getItems(userCompleteInfo)">
                <td>{{item.GebruikerId}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Voornaam}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Achternaam}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Email}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Wachtwoord}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
    </table>
    
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Tijd</th>
            <th>Locatie</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor = "let dataItem of MyReservations">
                <td>{{dataItem.Datum}}</td>
                <td>{{dataItem.Tijd}}</td>
                <td>{{dataItem.Locatie}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping everything in a div?

Comment: You can use both of them, add unique identifier as id  and wrap into addition div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>
<table id=“id1”>
        
        <thead>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>VOORNAAM</th>
            <th>ACHTERNAAM</th>
            <th>EMAIL</th>
            <th>WACHTWOORD</th>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor = "let item of getItems(userCompleteInfo)">
                <td>{{item.GebruikerId}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Voornaam}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Achternaam}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Email}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Wachtwoord}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
    </table>
    </div>
<div>
    <table id =“id2”>
        <thead>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Tijd</th>
            <th>Locatie</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor = "let dataItem of MyReservations">
                <td>{{dataItem.Datum}}</td>
                <td>{{dataItem.Tijd}}</td>
                <td>{{dataItem.Locatie}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Try this